# jQuery DataTable column filtering using multi-select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, filtering

For my application, I am using jQuery DataTable with materialize frame work. My table is having the following columns:

**1.Name 2.Position 3.Office 4.Age 5.Date and 6.Salary**

In that, I am dynamically creating a multi select filter for 'Office' and 'Age' column from the table response. I have tried my example in the following JSFiddle link.

[`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/12/)

But filtering is only working for single option and for multi select filtering it is not working. Also there is no relationship between '**Office**' and '**Age**' filters, both are working individually.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to separate the event of any change to select.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       dom: 'lrtip',
        initComplete: function () {
          this.api().columns([2]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            console.log(column);
            var select = $("#officeFltr"); 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
          } );
           this.api().columns([3]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            console.log(column);
            var select = $("#ageFltr"); 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
          } );
          $("#officeFltr,#ageFltr").material_select();
       }
    });

    $('#officeFltr').on('change', function(){
        var search = [];

      $.each($('#officeFltr option:selected'), function(){
            search.push($(this).val());
      });

      search = search.join('|');
      table.column(2).search(search, true, false).draw();  
    });

    $('#ageFltr').on('change', function(){
        var search = [];

      $.each($('#ageFltr option:selected'), function(){
            search.push($(this).val());
      });

      search = search.join('|');
      table.column(3).search(search, true, false).draw();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/16/)

Comment: Thank you..Now filter behavior is working fine. But how to achieve multiple options filtering? now filtering is working only for single option.

Comment: @rad11, This example is amazing but I have an issue. In chrome the datatable is getting loaded quickly(within 1-2 seconds) but in IE (11) it is taking 4-5 MINUTES for the same. I think initComplete is taking a lot of time in IE. do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score -1):

The above code will not work to make an exact match. For example, if I have a countries drop down list having the 2 countries 'Sudan' and 'South Sudan' and I am looking for Sudan, the above solution will return me both countries not only one.